# Computing the expected value of a double integral

Tags: integration

Consider the following double integral:

\begin{equation}
A = \displaystyle \int \limits_{\substack{x, y\ \in\ \mathcal{R}}} f(x,y)g(x,y) dxdy
\end{equation}

where $g(x,y)$ is a random variable distributed normally with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ where both the mean and variance are independent of $x$ and $y$, i.e., for each $x$ and $y$ in $\mathcal{R}$, $g(x,y)$ is i.i.d sampled from the same normal distribution with same mean and variance.

Then, can we say that the expected value of $A$ is given by $\mu B$ where

\begin{equation}
B = \displaystyle \int\limits_{\substack{x, y\ \in\ \mathcal{R}}} f(x,y) dxdy
\end{equation}

It seems obvious but how do I show it formally?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a stochastic integral

Comment: Thank you! I have modified the question, I was not sure if it was a stochastic integral, I have changed it

Comment: Is g(x,y) just a scalar or is it a random scalar field (normal variable at each point)? If the former then just express it as regular triple integral, if the latter then you need to say more about joint distribution. (Infinitely dimensional probability spaces can be tricky in general)

Comment: Hi @Radost I think it is the latter because $g(x,y)$ can assume different values for different $x$, $y$ but for each $x$ and $y$,  $g(x,y)$ is i.i.d sampled from the same normal distribution with same mean and variance. Is this sufficient to make the claim made in the question?

Comment: Heuristically it looks ok but if $g$ is like you claim then we have problems defining $A$. Each instance of the integrand has infinite variation and integral $A$ in either Lesbuge/Riemman sense would not converge - so defining the integral pointwise doesn't work. On the other hand summing uncountably many normal rv would result in infinite variance so $A$ would not have well defined distribution. Is this a purely abstract problem?

Comment: Thank you. It is a variation of a specific problem for example let us suppose $\mathcal{R}$ is a region and $g(x,y)$ is the number of people who want to travel from $x$ to $y$ and $f(x,y)$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$. Then, the integral A is the total distance traveled by all the people in $\mathcal{R}$. I am not too particular on the exact distribution of $g(x,y)$. I understand the issue you raise about convergence, it will help if instead $g(x,y)$ is a bounded symmetric distribution say a uniform distribution between $\mu - \sigma$ and $\mu + \sigma? Thank you for your help!